# In an angular2 component how do you get both the attribute text value as well as the bound variable?

Tags: angular, custom-component, angular2-template

Is there a way to get both the plain text value of an attribute as well as getting that attribute as an Input to the component? e.g. I have `@Input('c-failure') cFailure;` which gives me `this.cFailure` bound to the outer variable. component was created in outer template as `<c-component c-failure="failures.secondary['cause']">`.  I would like to get a variable whose value is "failures.secondary['cause']" as well as the variable bound to the value of outer this.failures.secondary.cause. I tried injecting the ElementRef, but it doesn't seem to have any or the attributes that were bound to an @Input.

Comment: So you want the value inside `failures.secondary['cause']` and the string `"failures.secondary['cause']"` as well?

Comment: Yep.  Exactly.  both the value and essentially the variable name...  the purpose is to save the dev having to put information that is already encoded into the variable name as separate attributes on the element when we could easily parse that existing bound attribute and set some sane defaults that they could override only if they needed to or if their input for the attribute didn't conform to what was expected.

Comment: Have you tried using @Attribute already? You can use that in the constructor to access the components attributes.

Comment: @Attribute does not work to get the value of the [c-failure] attribute...  Someone suggested that accessing the "DebugElement" might get me what I need, but I can't seem to find a way to get to the DebugElement from within a component itself.

Answer (score 1):

I would try the following leveraging `@Input` and `@Attribute` decorators. It seems that it's not possible to mix them on the same attribute

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test'
})
export class SomeComponent {
  @Input('c-failure')
  cFailure;

  constructor(@Attribute('c-failure-expr') cFailureExpr:string) {
  }
}
```

And use it this way:

```
<test [c-failure]="failures.secondary['cause']"
      c-failure-expr="failures.secondary['cause']"></test>
```

See this plunrk: https://plnkr.co/edit/yAOaMJzJKnTajwPdhSX8?p=preview.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I appreciate it.  Unfortunately, the specific point is to get both values from a single attribute.  I could obviously just send the information as a separate string in a different attribute,  The question was specifically about reducing duplication of effort by being able to get both from the single attribute.